# how to display the names of all my applied filters in django, and then remove one by one or any filter just by clicking on it

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

## Problem Statement

I am working on a data filtering project using Django, and I want to implement a feature where applied filters are displayed on the screen, and users can remove them by clicking on a cross (X) button next to the filter name.

### Requirements

- When a filter is applied, it should be displayed at the top of the screen with a cross (X) button, allowing users to remove that specific filter.
- For example, if I apply a filter for `charge_holder_name` with the value 'rock', the filter name 'charge_holder_name', so it should be shown at the top of the screen with a cross button, so I can remove this filter by clicking on it.
- The same case should apply when multiple filters are applied, such as 'date', 'amount', 'id', etc. All applied filter names should be displayed at the top of the screen.

### Implementation

#### Filters.py

```py
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus.widgets import DateTimePickerInput
import django_filters
from .models import RocCharge, RocCompany
from django import forms

# You can use a set comprehension to get unique values from RocCharge, loop to get unique values
unique_charge_holder_names = {i.charge_holder_name for i in RocCharge.objects.all()}
unique_company_names = {company.company_name for company in RocCompany.objects.all()}

class Orderfilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # Specify the choices as a list of tuples
    charge_holder_name = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name='charge_holder_name',
        lookup_expr='icontains',
        label='Charge Holder Name',
        choices=[(name, name) for name in unique_charge_holder_names]
    )

    # ... (other filter fields)

    class Meta:
        model = RocCharge
        fields = {
            'existing_old': ['exact'],
            'amount': ['lt', 'gt'],
            'date_of_creation': ['gte', 'lte'],
        }





###views.py---

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import RocCharge
from .filters import Orderfilter
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.http import HttpResponse
import csv

def Home(request):
    # Get the filtered data using RocCharge model from filters.py
    myfilter = Orderfilter(request.GET, queryset=RocCharge.objects.select_related('cin'))

    # Logic for clearing all filter buttons
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'remove_filter' in request.GET:
        filter_name = request.GET['remove_filter']
        myfilter.form[filter_name].initial = None
    elif 'remove_all_filters' in request.GET:
        for filter_name in myfilter.form.fields:
            myfilter.form[filter_name].initial = None

    # Showing or getting applied filters data
    combined_data = myfilter.qs.values(
        'srn_no', 'charge_id', 'charge_holder_name', 'date_of_creation', 'date_of_modification',
        'date_of_satisfaction', 'amount', 'address', 'existing_old',
        'cin__state', 'cin__city', 'cin__company_name', 'cin__company_cin', 'cin__sector', 'cin__industry'
    )

    from_date = request.GET.get('fromdate')
    to_date = request.GET.get('Todate')

    if from_date and to_date:
        combined_data = combined_data.filter(date_of_creation__gte=from_date, date_of_creation__lte=to_date)

    if 'download_csv' in request.GET:
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="institutions.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer(response)

        writer.writerow(['charge_holder_name', 'date_of_creation', 'dom',
        'dos', 'amount', 'existing_old',
        'cin__state', 'cin__city', 'cin__company_name', 'cin__company_cin', 'cin__sector', 'cin__industry'])

        for institution in myfilter.qs.values_list( 'charge_holder_name', 'date_of_creation', 'date_of_modification',
        'date_of_satisfaction', 'amount', 'existing_old',
        'cin__state', 'cin__city', 'cin__company_name', 'cin__company_cin', 'cin__sector', 'cin__industry'):
            writer.writerow(institution)

        return response

    context = {
        'myfilter': myfilter.form,
        'combined_data': combined_data,
    }
    
    # Pass the combined data to the template
    return render(request, 'central/Company_data.html', context)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.